# How do I get my nav links to spread evenly across and be centered in the page?

Tags: html, css, button, html-lists, nav

I'm a beginner and I'm coding a website for one of my school web projects. I'm trying to style the header so it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz58F.png

But the nav and "sign up for a library card" button are giving me some issues. I want to move the button over to it sits underneath the icons on the top but the button keeps moving to the left. I tried **float: right** but that doesn't seem to work. Here's my html and css.
Thanks!

```
</head>
<body>
<header>

<img class="logo clearfix" src="images/logo.png" alt="Charlotte County Library System Logo"/>
<img class="icons right clearfix" src="images/search.png" alt="Search Icon"/>
<img class="icons right clearfix" src="images/myaccount.png" alt="My Account Icon"/>
<button class="signup">Sign Up for a Library Card &gt;</button>
</header>

<div class="nav">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">CATALOG</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">FEES &amp; FINES</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">LOCATIONS &amp; HOURS</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">SERVICES</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after{
content:"";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

header{
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.logo{
float: left;
width: 400px;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.icons{
width: 45px;
padding: 10px;
}


.left{
float:left;
}
.right{
float: right;
}

button {
background-color: #3399CC;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #fff;
padding: 8px;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 70px;
font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
cursor: pointer;
}

nav{
background-color: #13DEA9;
width: 100%;
}
nav ul{
padding: 15px;


}

nav ul li{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
display: inline;


}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
margin: 70px;
color: white;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use flexbox. Here is your new css

```
nav {
    background-color: #13DEA9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jot6L15b/

Additionally i added a height attribute to the `nav` which you can set to whatever value you want and it will remain vertically centered also.

Comment: Also since its for a School & A Library. Do research on "Webdesign accessibility" if you want an A++++ on your project. This makes sure your site is usable by people with hearing and sight problems. Simple methods.

Comment: No problem. Please check the "green check" if my answer "answered" your question. Thanks!